# Jupyter Notebook - Notebooks created on another computer are very slow to open and lag on typing

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, lag

I've created a few notebooks on a previous Mac.
Since then, I've changed my Mac and reinstalled the new one from scratch, with the latest version of Anaconda (Python 2.7).
When I try to open these old notebooks, they are very long to open. Sometimes, it really takes 2-3 minutes in Safari. It sucks on loading MathJax/extensions/Safe.js.
Then, afterwards, it lags on typing : a few milliseconds between the keyboard action and the letters appearing in the cell.
I've been searching extensively on the web for this issue, but didn't find anything.

Uninstalling Anaconda and reinstalling again doesn't solve the issue.

Can it come from the fact that the Anaconda version I used to create the notebooks is probably not the same as the one I've installed on my new Mac ?

Thanks to all for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a change in the browser. Google Chrome is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Mac and noticed something while using jupyter. Check your Activity monitor. If CPU is working like hell even tough you are not doing anything because of the process "VTDecoderXPCService" do this

Restart everything:

- Right click quit on your browser in the dock
- ctrl+c in your terminal where the notebook launched and restart again with "jupyter notebook"

I and I guess most Mac users don't shut down or really quit applications. It's just a guess but maybe you have the same problem. I don't know yet what is causing it but the macbook get's hot, a bit laggy and jupyter takes 2-3x as long to open a notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Try Firefox. I think it is faster than Chrome for opening and viewing large notebook.